# Tensorflow TFWriter incorrect data serialization

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, tfrecord

I have a dataset created using ImageLabeller from MatLab, when trying to translate the dataset to TFrecord, according to the instructions in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md), some of the coordinates are incorrect, it appears as if the min is greater than the max.
I have tried removing the examples that fail but it seems the error is not related to that, failed examples always appear in the same position. I have tried with images from the [MODD2](https://github.com/bborja/modd) and from a dataset created with the imageLabeller using larger images and it works correctly.

The code used for the generation of the TFrecord files is the following:

```py
# MODD2 format: x y w h -> x,y are the top left corner coordinates
def read_drone_mat_file(file_number):

    # navigate to the modd2 directory
    bbox_d = []
    bbox_o = []
    filename = []

    # for each file, load it into data and append the obstacles information into the bbox list
    mat = os.listdir(drones_dir)[file_number]
    frame = os.path.join(drones_dir, mat)
    data = sio.loadmat(frame)

    for obj in data['drone']:
        bbox_d.append(obj)

    for obj in data['obstacles']:
        bbox_o.append(obj)
    filename.append(mat[0:9])

    return bbox_d, bbox_o, filename

# %% Helper function to create a tfexample for the drone data
def create_drone_tfexample(drones, obstacles, index, image_path):

    image_format = b'jpg'
    filename = os.listdir(image_path)[index+2]

    # load corresponding image (only use left images)
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(image_path, filename), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    wsize, hsize = (width, height)
    #basewidth = 640
    # if width > basewidth:
    #     wpercent = (basewidth/float(image.size[0]))
    #     hsize = int((float(image.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    #     wsize = basewidth
    #     image = image.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    #     buffered = io.BytesIO()
    #     image.save(buffered, format="JPEG")
    #     encoded_jpg = buffered.getvalue()

    filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0].encode('utf-8')
    create_drone_tfexample.source_id += 1
    source_id_s = "{}".format(create_drone_tfexample.source_id).encode('utf-8')

    # tfrecord features definition
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    # for each image
    for obj in drones:
        xmins.append(obj[0] / width)
        xmaxs.append((obj[0]+obj[2]) / width)
        ymins.append(obj[1] / height)
        ymaxs.append((obj[1]+obj[3]) / height)
        # until the drone dataset is available, all obstacles are class 0
        classes_text.append(bytes('drone', 'utf-8'))
        classes.append(2)

    for obj in obstacles:
        xmins.append(obj[0] / width)
        xmaxs.append((obj[0]+obj[2]) / width)
        ymins.append(obj[1] / height)
        ymaxs.append((obj[1]+obj[3]) / height)
        # until the drone dataset is available, all obstacles are class 0
        classes_text.append(bytes('obstacles', 'utf-8'))
        classes.append(1)

    print(source_id_s+b": "+filename)
    # print("xmins: {}".format(xmins))
    # print("xmaxs: {}".format(xmaxs))
    # print("ymins: {}".format(ymins))
    # print("ymaxs: {}".format(ymaxs))

    # create tf_example
    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(hsize),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(wsize),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(source_id_s),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))

    return tf_example


create_drone_tfexample.source_id = 0

# %% Create final dataset WARNING: Slow and destructive
train_writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(
    output_dir+'drone_train_truncated.tfrecord')
test_writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(output_dir+'drone_test_truncated.tfrecord')
drone_test_writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(
    output_dir + 'drone_only_test.tfrecord')
create_drone_tfexample.source_id = 0

# Drones dataset
for index, mat in enumerate(os.listdir(drones_dir)):
    boxes_d, boxes_o, filename = read_drone_mat_file(index)
    print()
    # Pass the bounding boxes to the create_tfexample function
    if index < 210:
        image_path = drones_image_root
        tf_example = create_drone_tfexample(
            boxes_d, boxes_o, index, image_path)

    # Write the tf_example into the dataset
    if random.randint(1, 100) <= 80:  # 80% Train  20% Validation
        train_writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
    else:
        test_writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
        drone_test_writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
```

The examples fail when trying to use them for training, to read the examples, I use the following code:

```py
# %% Extract images from dataset
dataset_file = "drone_only_test.tfrecord"
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
    "<path_to_dataset>"+dataset_file)

print('_______________________________________________________________________________________')
image_feature_description = {
    #             'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(hsize),
    #             'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(512),
    #             'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
    #             'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
    #             'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
    #             'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
    #             'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
    #             'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
    #             'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
    #             'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
    #             'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
    #             'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    'image/height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/filename': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'image/source_id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'image/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'image/format': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'image/object/bbox/xmin': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    'image/object/bbox/xmax': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    'image/object/bbox/ymin': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    'image/object/bbox/ymax': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    'image/object/class/text': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
    'image/object/class/label': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
}


def _parse_image_function(example_proto):
    # Parse the input tf.train.Example proto using the dictionary above.
    return tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_feature_description)


parsed_image_dataset = raw_dataset.map(_parse_image_function)

for image_features in parsed_image_dataset.take(10):
    image_raw = image_features['image/encoded'].numpy()
    display.display(display.Image(data=image_raw))
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(image_raw)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    image.save("out.jpg", format="JPEG")
    print(f'ID: {image_features["image/filename"]}')
    print(f'XMIN: {image_features["image/object/bbox/xmin"].values*640}')
    print(f'XMAX: {image_features["image/object/bbox/xmax"].values*640}')
    print(f'YMIN: {image_features["image/object/bbox/ymin"].values*480}')
    print(f'YMAX: {image_features["image/object/bbox/ymax"].values*480}')
    print('---------------------')
    print(
        f'WIDTH: {image_features["image/object/bbox/xmax"].values*640 - image_features["image/object/bbox/xmin"].values*640}')
    print(
        f'HEIGHT: {image_features["image/object/bbox/ymax"].values*480 - image_features["image/object/bbox/ymin"].values*480}')
```

For the example in the fourth position, the output is the following:

```
ID: b'color_00000036'
XMIN: [179. 175.   5.]
XMAX: [387. 210.  21.]
YMIN: [263. 193. 242.]
YMAX: [372.   6. 248.]
---------------------
WIDTH: [208.  35.  16.]
HEIGHT: [ 109. -187.    6.]
```

The matlab output for the same image is the following:

```
ground_truth =

   179   175     5
   263   193   242
   208    35    16
   109    69     6
```

The versions used are the following:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Python 3.7.9 64-bit
- Tensorflow 2.4.0
- Scipy 1.5.4
- Tensorflow Object Detection API master

Comment: Could you please post the error traceback and if possible, the dataset that you are trying to convert to tfrecord?

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being related to scipy.io.loadmat() casting the data into np.uint8, the solution is to pass mat_dtype=True as a parameter so it loads everything as np.float64.
Not the most efficient thing but it works.

Thank you very much.